# getting this render flex error due to an icon button

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am facing this issue from yesterday never encounter this kind of error when I was not fetching info from database but as soon as I had backend in my app I somehow manage to break it :(

please help me fix it

PS: I am learning flutter from last week so please don't throw complex words that I might not understand right now

My error image:
[image: image of my error in console]

I find out that this problem occurs due to leading icon button in my `gridTileBar` but like I've said before this problem is very specific, only happens when I try to fetch data from my server but when I try to load products from dummy data this problem never occurs.

Please someone helps me I am nearing completion of this module but I still can't check the functionality of my products favorite status in my server, because I cant, render that button while using the database

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import '../providers/product.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';


class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);

    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);

    return ClipRRect(

      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),

      child: GridTile(

        child: GestureDetector(

          onTap: () {

            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(

              ProductDetailScreen.routeName,

              arguments: product.id,

            );

          },
          child: Image.network(

            product.imageUrl,

            fit: BoxFit.cover,

          ),

        ),

        footer: GridTileBar(

          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
```

This part of the code creating a problem as per my knowledge because if I comment this part out no error.

```
          leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(  
              icon: Icon(
                product.isFavourite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: () {
                product.toggleFavouriteStatus();
              },
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            product.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              cart.addItem(
                  productId: product.id,
                  price: product.price,
                  title: product.title);
              Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text("Added item to the Cart!"),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: "UNDO",
                    onPressed: () {
                      cart.removeSingleItem(product.id);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

the above code is for a sub widget that creates grid tiles for my `gridview` that I want to render in my app main overview screen.

Code for the `gridview` down below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './product_item.dart';

import '../providers/products_provider.dart';


class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {

  final bool showFavourite;

  ProductsGrid(this.showFavourite);


  @override

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context); //object of Products_provider class 
    final products = showFavourite? productsData.favouriteItems: productsData.items;
    

    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: products.length,

      itemBuilder: (ctx,i)=>ChangeNotifierProvider.value(  
        value: products[i],                             
        child:ProductItem( ),
      ),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2, 
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2, 
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10 

        ),
      );
  }
}`
```

these widgets listen to my product provider class code of which is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'dart:convert'; //to convert data into json

import '../secrets.dart';


class Product with ChangeNotifier {

  final String id;

  final String title;

  final String description;

  final double price;

  final String imageUrl;

  bool isFavourite; //this is not final because it is changeable attribute of the product based on user preferences at any given time

  Product({

    @required this.id,

    @required this.title,

    @required this.description,

    @required this.price,

    @required this.imageUrl,

    this.isFavourite = false, 
                
    });

    var secrets = Secrets();
    
    //function that help to roll back previous favourite values in case of an error
    void _setFavValue(bool newValue){
      isFavourite = newValue;
      notifyListeners();
    }

    Future<void> toggleFavouriteStatus() async {

      var oldStatus = isFavourite; //this var is used to start the inital value of favourite before change
      isFavourite = !isFavourite;  //toggling the value of isFavourite from true to false and vice versa
      notifyListeners(); //notifying all its listners

      final url = "${secrets.fireBaseUrl}/products/$id.json";

      try {
             final response = await http.patch(
                url, 
                body: json.encode({
                    'isFavourite':isFavourite,
                 }
             ));
             
             if(response.statusCode >= 400){
                 _setFavValue(oldStatus);
             }
      }
      catch(err){
        _setFavValue(oldStatus);
      }

    }
  
}
```

Please help me figure this out. I've been struggling for two days now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your code, i think it happens because you're comparing two booleans, out of which, one is null.

So to tackle this,

Try making a function which returns a future, and in that, initialise the boolean variable, so that it can't be empty.